# C++ Builder XE2, receiving tcp requests

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, c++builder

I want to write a tcp-listener within my application, so it can be controlled by others applications.

For that I use the following snippet I found (as an example for the use of listener).

I worked with p2p-connections and Sockets once already in C#.NET, but it's either too long ago or too differently. I expect the code to stop at the `listen()` command and wait until there is a connection request at that port. However, instead it just continues with the next lines. Usually my Firewall should also tell me, if there is some internet-activity-attempt, but it stays silent.

What would be the next step to actually know whether there is a connection request?
Can I trigger that with a HTTP-request for `127.0.0.1:27015` using a browser?
Or could this be archived easier?

```
#include <winsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int portlisten(){
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = 0;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    sockaddr_in service;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for listening for incoming connection requests.
    ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port for the socket that is being bound.
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    service.sin_port = htons(27015);

    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & service, sizeof (service));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"bind function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(ListenSocket);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Listen for incoming connection requests
    // on the created socket
    if (listen(ListenSocket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        wprintf(L"listen function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    wprintf(L"Listening on socket...\n");

    iResult = closesocket(ListenSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expect the code to stop at the listen() command and wait until there is a connection request at that port.

No.  You are thinking of `accept()` instead.  `listen()` merely opens the port and then exits immediately.  You have to then use `accept()` in a loop to accept individual client connections.  It returns a new `SOCKET` that you use to exchange data with that specific client.  You can use `select()` to know when a new client is trying to connect before then calling `accept()`, or you can let `accept()` block the calling thread until a client connects.

Instead of writing your own socket API code, you should use a pre-existing TCP server component, like the VCL's native `TServerSocket` component, or Indy's `TIdTCPServer` component.

Comment: thanks for the info! I would like to use `TServerSocket` instead, however, even with adding the komponent according to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Installing_Socket_Components the component doesn't appear in my Tools. Also, when I try to use `TServerSocket Jsocket;` it says `"undefined Symbol TServerSocket"`. I have `#include <vcl.h>`... anything else needed?

Comment: Installing the `dclsockets` package works fine for me. As for the error, `TServerSocket` is declared in `System.Win.ScktComp.hpp`. And being a `TObject` descendant, you must instantiate it dynamically at runtime: `TServerSocket *Jsocket = new TServerSocket(DesiredOwner);`

Comment: Just nothing that if you use `TIdTCPServer`, it only supports blocking mode ... don't waste time learning it if your project requires non-blocking sockets :)  TServerSocket should work fine, IDK why they make you jump through hoops to use it.

Comment: I guess `#include <ScktComp.hpp>` was missing. However, if I try to create a new TServerSocket using `TServerSocket *Sock = new TServerSocket(NULL);` I get an link error `unresolved external 'System::Win::Scktcomp::TServerSocket::' `. I am using a console-application. could this be the problem?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` are deprecated, that is why they are not installed by default anymore.

Comment: @Julian: your project is likely missing a reference to the run-time package that actually implements the `TServerSocket` class. `dclsockets` is a design-time package to get the components into the IDE, and `ScktComp.hpp` let's the C++ compiler know about them, but the linker also needs to know about them, and that piece is apparently missing in your project. I will look up the run-time package name in a few minutes and get back to you.

Comment: Normally if something gets deprecated it's because there is a new option that's better ... but that doesn't seem to be the case for dclsockets. Indy Sockets are blocking-only, and TTcpClient doesn't work in non-blocking mode.

Comment: Embarcadero uses Indy for their own stuff, and Indy has been bundled with the IDE since Delphi v6, which are likely to be driving factors in why the `dclsocket` components were deprecated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, so you're supposed to create a new thread for every client socket your code uses?